# setFeature(String, boolean) is undefined for the type javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-parsing, javax

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);`
```

setNamespaceAware() is working on DocumentBuilderFactory. But compilation error is coming for setFeature().

*The method setFeature(String, boolean) is undefined for the type DocumentBuilderFactory*

Any suggestions for resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the classpath first to see where DocumentBuilderFactory comes from. For example, xerces has the javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory class without the setFeature method.

Comment: It is coming from xml-apis.jar

Comment: What is that, and where is it coming from?

Comment: So this might be your problem. xml-apis.jar contains a DocumentBuilderFactory class which hides the DocumentBuilderFactory class from JDK, but does not implement the specification completely.

Make sure that the DocumentBuilderFactory class from JDK is used. Try removing xml-apis.jar and see what happens.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but no direct dependency on xml-apis.jar. It turned out it was indirectly referenced by jacoco-maven-plugin dependency. After adding `<scope>test</scope>` to the `jacoco-maven-plugin` dependency the problem is gone.